# NSBrowser simple example

Tags: xcode, macos, nsbrowser

I need to display the file system in the NSBrowser. Please provide with some sample examples.
**OR** is there any other way to take path as input from the users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at SimpleCocoaBrowser sample code.

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/SimpleCocoaBrowser/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: thanx a lot. can u plz tell me the way to take path as input. how can i get file save dialog box in my app. i want the path of selected file/directory

Comment: This page is not found

Comment: It's in the archive now https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/SimpleCocoaBrowser/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008872